# show progress bar with out freezing the app

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

I have a ListActivity which launches another Activity based on the list selection. This second Activity needs to load data by parsing from the xml file and as such there is a noticeable delay between when the user clicks on an item and when the Activity displays.

Between this process user have to be indicated with progress bar at the bottom of the screen with out freezing the activity.

Comment: use UIThread for progressbar showing and AsyncThread for Network activity.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by freezing . is the app crashes  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class which enables you to do background processing and publish processing status without halting the main Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use some GUI library, there will be this concept: You have one thread that is for GUI events, in Java-Swing called the "Event Dispatching Thread" [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread), in Android as well as SWT, it's called the UI-Thread. This thread is responsible for all GUI events and manipulation. Time consuming actions must be done on another thread so the UI doesn't block/freezes.

(I think it is important to understand this basic concept of UI development, rather than just use AsyncTask and think that this is something Android specific)

**EDIT**

- [painless threading in Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)
- [Threads in Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)
- [EDT Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)